# HTML5 Desktop Notofications

Tags: html, notifications, push-notification

I have read some articles concerning HTML5 Desktop Notifications. I have googled for a while if Desktop notitification works when the browser is closed but couldn't get any answer.

My understanding is that if it is a desktop notification then the browser needs not to be opened and the notification should work.

1)
My question is if the browser is closed, will a user be notified?

2)
Does notifications open the browser if the browser is closed?

I need some explanation.

Thanks alot.

Comment: No, HTML and any JavaScript API's you use with it are ran inside the browser, they can't do anything if the browser isn't open.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notifications will only be displayed if the browser is running AND your app is opened in one of the tabs or windows.